# Why there is a gack id 84857376-59104 (-1825867773) when trying to upload an unmanaged package containing data cloud streams?

Tags: gack, salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

When I try to upload an unmanaged package with data streams and calculated insights, I receive `An unexpected error occurred when uploading your package. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 84857376-59104 (-1825867773)` - What is that? Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a SF Support case.

They explained that packaging CRM streams directly in the unmanaged package is not supported but instead should be done through data kits, when data kits can be then added to unmanaged package.

Interesting though that this help article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_packaging_in_customer_360_audiences.htm&type=5 claims that CRM Data streams can be directly packaged while in fact they cannot be.

Comment: Would it make sense to enrich an answer with link to the help article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_packaging_in_customer_360_audiences.htm&type=5? `You can also add CRM data streams to an unmanaged package using a data kit.`

Comment: Checking the [metadata coverage report](https://dx-extended-coverage.my.salesforce-sites.com/docs/metadata-coverage/59) is a good way to discover what can and cannot be packaged. It also makes sense to move away from 1GP unmanaged packages to 2GP unlocked packages.

Comment: @kurunve the link you provided claims that CRM Data streams can be directly packaged while in fact they cannot be.

Comment: @PhilW Strange, but this metadata coverage report doesn't include 1GP unmanaged package coverage

Comment: I guess because they are entirely superseded by 2GP unlocked?

Comment: what do you mean by saying they are entirely superseded by unlocked packages?